# Difference between struct and class in Swift, also SwiftUI not updating

Tags: swift, class, struct, swiftui

I ran in to some problems and wrote some basic variant to show the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PersonStruct {
    // Requires @State because self.name is immutable otherwise
    @State var name:String

    init (_ name: String) { self.name = name }
    
    func changeName(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print (self.name)
    }
}

class PersonClass {
    var name:String

    init (_ name: String) { self.name = name }
    
    func changeName(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print (self.name)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var person1:PersonStruct = PersonStruct("Peter S.")
    var person2:PersonClass = PersonClass("Peter C.")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(person1.name)
            .padding()
            Text(person2.name)
            .padding()
            
            Button("Change name") {
                person1.changeName("Trevor")
                person1.name = "Trevor"

                person2.changeName("Trevor")
                person2.name = "Trevor"

                print("---")
                print (person1.name)
                print (person2.name)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .font(.title)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The person variables behave different, pressing the button changes the name of person2 from "Peter C" to Trever - as seen by "print" in the console.
But the name of person1 will not be changed, it stays at "Peter S." ...

So, the struct does not seem to work at all.

And in both cases, the Text outputs in the View will both not change - "Peter C" and "Peter S" stay visible.

Why does the content from person1 not change?
I even used both the function "changeName()" and also tried to set the name directly.
To no avail :-(

Comment: You should not use `@State` in a non SwiftUI struct, I.e one that doesn’t conform to `View`. You should on the other hand use `@State` for both your properties in `ContentView`. Fix that and come back if you still have an issue

Comment: Removing the @State in the struct gave "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable" as mentioned above.
But the "mutating" from vadian did solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's **not** required that `name` in the struct is marked with `@State`, actually it's wrong anyway, just make the function `mutating`

```
struct PersonStruct {
    var name : String

    init (_ name: String) { self.name = name }
    
    mutating func changeName(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print (self.name)
    }
}
```

To be able to observe the class adopt `ObservableObject` and add the property wrapper `@Published`

```
class PersonClass : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name:String

    init (_ name: String) { self.name = name }
    
    func changeName(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print (self.name)
    }
}
```

In the view declare the struct as `@State` and the class as `@StateObject`

```
@State private var person1 = PersonStruct("Peter S.")
@StateObject private var person2 = PersonClass("Peter C.")
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, many thanks!
Using "@State" instead of "@StateObject" seems to work too for person2 ...

Comment: The rules are: `@State` for value types and `@StateObject` for reference types.